# Adding CSS to Facebook Like Box

Tags: css, facebook, stylesheet, facebook-like, xfbml

I'm trying to add css styling to Facebook Like Box XFBML file but it doesn't take the stylesheet the regular way – its own stylesheet comes after yours. So I did some search and found posts that said to add css="youstylesheetlink.css" to the fb:like-box like this:

```
<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/example" width="496" height="120" show_faces="true" border_color="" stream="false" header="false" css="http://example.com/css/style.css?2"></fb:like-box>
```

But no matter what I try it doesn't take the stylesheet. Can anybody guide me how I can achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: This cannot be done.  [See this thread too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077476/embedded-facebook-like-box-wont-let-me-style-it-why/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could do it, it would be [documented here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).

IMHO, you cannot tinker with Facebook's corporate branding... they want a consistent user experience everywhere on the Internet, otherwise, you'll have people not trusting things that look like homemade "like" boxes.

Also see this...

[Embedded Facebook Like-Box won't let me style it. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077476/embedded-facebook-like-box-wont-let-me-style-it-why/)

Answer (score 3):

Facebook used to allow you to pass custom css to their like box, and that is why you see examples of it happening.  But they stopped allowing you to do this for now.

Comment: This is the correct answer, now it's simply take it or leave it from what they offer you (unless you can have some deal with them directly).

Answer (score 2):

Unless your website happens to have the same matching protocol, domain and port as the Facebook `iframe`, you can not modify it because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Alex,so it can not be done? There are some tutorial sites that do this but I can't replicate their result. Plus my XFBML code looks different from theirs.

Comment: @Shubo Is the resulting HTML contained in an `iframe` ?

Comment: @Shubo: Even the XFBML code results in rendering an iFrame... AFAIK, this cannot be done.

Comment: @Sparky672: can I do it using FB.XFBML.parse?

Comment: @Alex, yes it results in iframe.

Comment: @Shubo:  If you could, it would be documented [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).  IMHO, you cannot tinker with Facebook's corporate branding... they want a consistent user experience everywhere on the Internet, otherwise, you'll have people not trusting things that look like homemade "like" boxes.