# Should be a simple IE7 css fix, but I can't figure it out

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, facebook-like

Check out http://campbellcustomcoatings.com/ in something other than IE7, then in IE7. You can see that in IE7, the facebook like button is more to the right and up. I'd like to push it down in IE7 as it is in any other browser. I've tried for over an hour and I can't get it to budge.

Comment: I put IE8 into compatibility view (sort-of simulation of IE7) because I don't have IE7 and the Like button just disappeared.  I think you might have more problems than just CSS.

Comment: Try it again. i was just making some changes and messed some things up. It should be working again now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the following for IE7 and it seemed to place the button in a similar position to how it looks in Chrome.

```
#fblike {
    margin-left:57px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

I think the problem is coming from the floated `<li>` items. If you highlight the elements using Chrome DOM browser (<kbd>F12</kbd> then select the *Elements* tab) you can see that because floats exist, the "nav", "container" and "fblike" `<div>`s do not strictly *contain* all the child elements. You could create a horizontal navigation without using floats. A list apart has a [nice article on lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/) which may help cross-browser rendering issues (which I am always getting with floats!)

Answer (score 0):

Just add some left and top margin to the iframe. to do this for just IE7, do:

```
*margin-top:20px; /*20 looked good for me */
*margin-left:20px;
```

Keep in mind that this won't validate as legit CSS (at least, i don't think it does) but other browsers will ignore it and it works fine.

Comment: I have an IE7 style sheet and I tried that already. Doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Catfish from what i can see, you tried that on the parent `div` ...have you tried it on the actual `iframe`?

Comment: @Catfish interesting. It's working when i apply it from IE dev tools. I'm intrigued. *keeps fiddling*

Comment: @Catfish what about applying some IE-specific padding to the parent div? (if it works i'll edit the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you're talking about as I have the same issue.  The button looks different (size and position) in various versions of IE than in other browsers.

However, you cannot modify or apply CSS to a Facebook Like Box plugin because its content is contained within an `<iframe>` element coming from the Facebook server.

The only styling options you have are the ones given to you by Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

More info:

[Embedded Facebook Like-Box won't let me style it. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077476/embedded-facebook-like-box-wont-let-me-style-it-why)

[Adding CSS to Facebook Like Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273462/adding-css-to-facebook-like-box)

Comment: I think I just need to set styles to the div that I put around the IFrame and I think it should work, but I can't figure it out for sure.

Comment: @Catfish:  Yeah, I have mine in a container div but it has a background color.  So my container always appears in the same position even if the button inside moves around or changes.

Comment: can't you apply the styles to the iframe then?

Comment: @Catfish:  I believe the `<iframe>` styles are limited to what FB allows, size, etc.  The container is a fixed width with a dynamic height, padding, colored background and rounded corners.  The `<iframe>` is inside with a "fixed" width & height.